# Can i use result of AsyncTask class after .execute statement

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Suppose I have A class body as:(It is just a rough design of a class.. )

```
   class XYZ
   {


         //Some Code here
         submitBTN.setOnClickListener(..){
                    ABC obj=new ABC();
                    obj.execute();
                    Toast(obj.result).show();
                 }

         class ABC extends AsynTask<String,Void,String>{
         String result=null;
         ..
         ..
         doInBackground(..){
              ..
              ..
            return "success";

            }
          onPostExecute(String result){
                this.result=result;
               }
    }
    }
```

My Question is Will Toast Show "Success" or it will show "null";
Since we are starting a another thread in background
so obj.execute is a blocking statement or not 
i mean will the control move to the next statement after .execute statement or will it wait untill the background thread completes?

Comment: No. Impossible. The toast is called before the asynctask runs and certly before it ends. You should put that toast in the onPostExecute() of the AsyncTask.

Comment: AsyncTask does not block. The result will be most likely be null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the result of OnPostExecute() to main activity because AsyncTask is a separate class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a)

Answer (score 0):

The control will move to toast because Asyctask task executes in its own thread. But obj.result will give null result because you there is no guarantee that result will be set before toast execution.

Comment: that means obj.execute is a non-blocking statementIf i have a seperate AsynTask Class and i want to show success in Toast then can i do that..if yes then please tell how to do it

Comment: Yes its non blocking

Answer (score 0):

You can use Interfaces

```
public interface OnStuffDone{
 void onResult(String result);
 }

public AsyncTask<String,Void,String> abc (OnStuffDone onStuffDone){
   return new AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
       ...
    doInBackground(..){

         ...
        return "success";

        }
      onPostExecute(String result){
            onStuffDone.onResult(result);
           }

       }

      abc(new OnStuffDone
      ...
      @Override
     public void onResult(String result){
     //Show result
     }
    ).execute()
```